# What is wrong with my Eevee render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

it's my project that rendered Eevee
and some slashes comes out
i never put that in my project
and in cycles, that's never apeared

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid you'll have to give more details than you have before we can help you. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question and add more details explaining what you mean by "some slashes comes out i never put that in my project".

Comment: Please provide more details. Is there any geometry that you might have hidden? Were you using some shading tricks or something? Are you doing any kind of compositing on the result.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I found that motion blur is reason of that slashes.
Thanks for viewing my question.

I fixed that by turning off my motion blur.

Comment: Thanks for your self-answer, too,